# Jpa create native query from form input

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

Usually during my work hours i spend a lot of time querying the db(oracle) and parsing blob from various table where the streams that we receive are stored.
There are various type of stream so i was trying to made a simple webapp where i write the select statement and it returns all the stream parsed accordingly.
My problem is that using jpa and executing the simple native query:

```
select B_BODY from TABLE_B where TRANSACTION_ID = 'GG-148c-01502790743907855009';
```

the statement doesn't return anything but querying directly the database return the record.
this is my java code:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<Object[]> retrieveBlobs(String squery) {
    squery = squery + " and rownum <= "+maxResults;
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(squery);
    List<Object[]> resultList = query.getResultList();
    return resultList;        
}
```

this is the sql generated:

```
Hibernate: 
select
    B_BODY 
from
    TABLE_B
where
    TRANSACTION_ID ='GG-148c-01502790743907855009' 
    and rownum <= 100
```

i know that this way might seems weird but our team spend a lot of time trying to tokenize the stored streams(the code that identify how to parse the stream is also stored in the tables).Useless to say this application is going to be used only internally.there is a way to just execute the query as it is and retrieve the correct output?

Comment: Execute a query directly from a webapp? Have you considered the security risks this may imply? What does your DBA say about it?

Comment: As i said is going to be used internally only from people who already can execute query on the db.Btw i already asked to the dba(myself) and he agree.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried to reproduce your problem on MariaDB (with mysql-connector-java + hibernate) but selecting a lob with native query was working properly.

You can try to create entities which will be holding your blob and check if this would help. Just make a standard entity with `@Lob` annotation over your lob column.

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries(
        @NamedQuery(name = FIND_ALL, query = "SELECT m FROM LobEntity m")
)
public class LobEntity {

    public static final String FIND_ALL = "PhpEntity.findAll";
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "lob")
    private byte[] lob;

    //Use Blob class if you want to use streams.
    //@Column(name = "lob")
    //@Lob
    //private Blob lob;

}
```